# Best practices for multilingual open-source book?

Tags: macros, translator

I'm writing an open-source book in two languages (English and Russian) and there are volunteers who would like to help with translation to other languages.

My first idea is simple: let there be conditional commands like \EN{}, \RU{}, \FR{}, etc, for the text for each language. So far so good. But I change some parts of my book continuously, add another text, etc. What the best idea to mark these parts so then translators would pull repository and re-check their translations and/or add new? It's very easy to miss a line in text editor or two...

Well, I probably can rename \FR{text} command to \FRRecheck{} each time I change something, as a flag to French translator.

What if I add new text, maybe I can add command like \FRNeed{} as a flag to translator?

So what do you think? Are there any well-known TeX/LaTeX multilingual open-source projects to get ideas from?

TIA!

Comment: Can't people view a `diff` comparing the English/Russian version last translated with the current English/Russian version? `latexdiff` might make the output nicer but that's just fancy stuff on top. Or look at how software projects manage this (e.g. how does Mozilla handle this for Firefox?). But basically a diff will highlight the changed lines...

Answer (score 3):

For books, I suggest to use a translation memory system. For example, an open-source OmegaT: http://www.omegat.org/. As far as I know, this tools supports TeX.